# How to get user password before it is hashed?

Tags: 8, users, hooks

In Drupal 8 - how can I get the user password BEFORE it is hashed?

I need to create the user at two other services through API's, so the user can use the same credentials to login to all platoforms.

I tried this:

```
function MYMODULE_entity_presave(UserInterface $account) {
#Here I can see the password - but not access it.  
var_dump($account);

#If I use the toArray function - I can access the password, but now it is hashed. 
$account = $account->toArray();
```

How (if possible) can I do it?

Comment: A hook_form_alter and then adding your own submit handler to the form should do it. There's plenty of examples out there to get you started with

Comment: Thanks, I will check it out! :)